# Create an alias for making same ant command call that works for any directories

Tags: linux

Currently, I have to go to different directories and call an ant command. (for ex. ant clean build).

Is there a way to create an alias, say antBuild for that so I could go to any directory and antBuild.

I can't create an alias with "alias antBuild = 'ant clean build'" because it complains there ant clean build is not a valid command since it is a directory specific command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the spaces around the `=`.

```
alias antBuild='ant clean build'
```